# Facebook Graph API: how to retrieve all comments related to the Ad?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

Facebook Graph API: how to retrieve all comments related to the Ad?

For now I am only able to get comments if the ad has video_id in object_story_spec (Ad -> creatives -> object_story_spec -> video_information -> video_id, then I pass video_id/comments to the Graph API).